# Uneven spacing using \vspace inside \itemize in beamer

Tags: beamer, spacing, itemize

I have a slide that is just an itemize.  I am using `\vspace{.5cm}` to space things out.  For some reason between two of the bullets the spacing is larger than the others and I have to use `\vspace{.015cm}` to get a similar visual result.

How do I get even spaced bullets in a predictable way/what am I doing wrong?

My full slide is:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\floor{\lfloor}{\rfloor}
\begin{frame}{Proof 2: Symmetry Preserving Maps}
\begin{itemize}
    \item  $\mathbb{Z}_2$ symmetry on $\mathbb{R}$: $x\longleftrightarrow -x$ 
    \vspace{.5cm}
    \pause
    \item $\mathbb{Z}_2$ symmetry on $S^d$: $x\longleftrightarrow -x$ 
    \vspace{.5cm}
    \pause
    \item $f_i:S^d\to \mathbb{R}$ given by $x\mapsto\mu_i(H^+(x))-\mu_i(H^-(x))$
    \vspace{.5cm}
    \pause
    \item $f_i(-x) = \mu(H^+(-x))-\mu(H^-(-x)) = \mu(H^-(x))-\mu(H^+(x)) = -f_i(x)$
    \vspace{.015cm}
    \pause
    \item $F:S^d\to\mathbb{R}^d$ given by $x\mapsto(f_1,f_2,\cdots,f_d)$
    \vspace{.5cm}
    \pause
    \item $F(-x) = -F(x)$
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

using `\vspace{0.015cm}` between the offending pair:
[image: using <code>\vspace{0.015cm}</code> between the offending pair]
With `\vspace{0.5cm}` between each:
[image: With <code>\vspace{0.5cm}</code> between each]
Without any `\vspace` command between the offending pair:
[image: Without any <code>\vspace</code> command between the offending pair]

Comment: Please, add a suitable document preamble in order to be able to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tgpagella}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Proof 2: Symmetry Preserving Maps}
        \begin{itemize}[<+->]\setlength\itemsep{3ex}
            \item  $\mathbb{Z}_2$ symmetry on $\mathbb{R}$: $x\longleftrightarrow -x$ 
            \item $\mathbb{Z}_2$ symmetry on $S^d$: $x\longleftrightarrow -x$ 
            \item $f_i:S^d\to \mathbb{R}$ given by $x\mapsto\mu_i(H^+(x))-\mu_i(H^-(x))$
            \item $f_i(-x) = \mu(H^+(-x))-\mu(H^-(-x)) = \mu(H^-(x))-\mu(H^+(x)) = -f_i(x)$
            \item $F:S^d\to\mathbb{R}^d$ given by $x\mapsto(f_1,f_2,\cdots,f_d)$
            \item $F(-x) = -F(x)$
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is a very simple solution.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It's a typical problem due to an unexpected spurious space.

The longer line ends almost at the boundary of the available space and there is a space (due to the end-of-line in the input) between the last `$` and `\vspace`. Thus the paragraph consists of two lines, the second of which only contains `\vspace`.

When `\vspace` is issued in LR-mode (that is, when paragraphs are being formed) it inserts an invisible item in the paragraph. The best way to deal with `\vspace` is issuing it *between* paragraphs.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\floor{\lfloor}{\rfloor}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Proof 2: Symmetry Preserving Maps}
\begin{itemize}
    \item  $\mathbb{Z}_2$ symmetry on $\mathbb{R}$: $x\longleftrightarrow -x$ 

    \vspace{.5cm}
    \pause
    \item $\mathbb{Z}_2$ symmetry on $S^d$: $x\longleftrightarrow -x$ 

    \vspace{.5cm}
    \pause
    \item $f_i:S^d\to \mathbb{R}$ given by $x\mapsto\mu_i(H^+(x))-\mu_i(H^-(x))$

    \vspace{.5cm}
    \pause
    \item $f_i(-x) = \mu(H^+(-x))-\mu(H^-(-x)) = \mu(H^-(x))-\mu(H^+(x)) = -f_i(x)$

    \vspace{.5cm}
    \pause
    \item $F:S^d\to\mathbb{R}^d$ given by $x\mapsto(f_1,f_2,\cdots,f_d)$

    \vspace{.5cm}
    \pause
    \item $F(-x) = -F(x)$
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, it's much better to use the available tools, instead of relying on manual spacing, like in Herbert's answer.

In my opinion `beamer` should also have a template for setting list related parameters.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\floor{\lfloor}{\rfloor}

\xpatchcmd{\itemize}
  {\def\makelabel}
  {\usebeamertemplate{itemize body}\def\makelabel}
  {}{}

\defbeamertemplate*{itemize body}{default}{} % default is doing nothing

\setbeamertemplate{itemize body}{%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0.5cm}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Proof 2: Symmetry Preserving Maps}

\begin{itemize}[<+->]
    \item  $\mathbb{Z}_2$ symmetry on $\mathbb{R}$: $x\longleftrightarrow -x$ 

    \item $\mathbb{Z}_2$ symmetry on $S^d$: $x\longleftrightarrow -x$ 

    \item $f_i:S^d\to \mathbb{R}$ given by $x\mapsto\mu_i(H^+(x))-\mu_i(H^-(x))$

    \item $f_i(-x) = \mu(H^+(-x))-\mu(H^-(-x)) = \mu(H^-(x))-\mu(H^+(x)) = -f_i(x)$

    \item $F:S^d\to\mathbb{R}^d$ given by $x\mapsto(f_1,f_2,\cdots,f_d)$

    \item $F(-x) = -F(x)$
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The output is the same.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setitemize{label=\usebeamerfont*{itemize item}%
\usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize item}
\usebeamertemplate{itemize item}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Proof 2: Symmetry Preserving Maps}
\begin{itemize}[itemsep=.5cm]
    \item  $\mathbb{Z}_2$ symmetry on $\mathbb{R}$: $x\longleftrightarrow -x$ 
    \pause
    \item $\mathbb{Z}_2$ symmetry on $S^d$: $x\longleftrightarrow -x$ 
    \pause
    \item $f_i:S^d\to \mathbb{R}$ given by $x\mapsto\mu_i(H^+(x))-\mu_i(H^-(x))$
    \pause
    \item $f_i(-x) = \mu(H^+(-x))-\mu(H^-(-x)) = \mu(H^-(x))-\mu(H^+(x)) = -f_i(x)$
    \pause
    \item $F:S^d\to\mathbb{R}^d$ given by $x\mapsto(f_1,f_2,\cdots,f_d)$
    \pause
    \item $F(-x) = -F(x)$
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Setting the vertical separation between items manually is not recommended besides being non-error free. `enumitem` package is typically used for this plus adjustment of many parameters of list environment. Bad news is that `enumitem` destroys the way `beamer` handles list environments and redefines labels and colors. So, we need to tell `enumitem` explicitly to keep `beamer` settings. This is done by the following piece of code:

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setitemize{label=\usebeamerfont*{itemize item}%
\usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize item}
\usebeamertemplate{itemize item}}
```

Finally, pass the option `[itemsep=.5cm]` to `itemize`:

Comment: Using `enumitem` with `beamer` is not at all recommended.

Comment: @egreg Yes, I gave that note "Bad news is that `enumitem` destroys ..."

Comment: This is very helpful.  I accepted Herbert's solution as it is what I ended up using, but the enumitem packege is very good to know about. Thank you!